# Is it possible to create flow charts(not UML) from solidity code in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ethereum, blockchain, solidity

I have a solidity code in my vscode. Is it possible if i can convert or create a flow chart out of it. Is there any inbuilt extension for that?

Answer (score 0):

For contract flow, you can use this extension:

**Name: solidity
Id: JuanBlanco.solidity
Description: Ethereum Solidity Language for Visual Studio Code
Version: 0.0.165
Publisher: Juan Blanco
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity**

After installing you can able to see some options on top of your contract code like this:
[image: Options for flow]

These are clickable options. To get the flow chart just click on **graph(this)** option